# ios - Missing required modules: 'Crypto'

Tags: ios, swift, cryptography

I want to use this Swift library in my iOS app: https://github.com/steemit/swift-steem. I typed `swift package update` and `swift package generate-xcodeproj`, then created an xcode workspace which consists of the generated xcodeproj from the library and the xcodeproj generated for my ios app.

Afterwards, I installed the `secp256k1` pod from Cocoapods.

Then I typed `import Steem` on `ViewController.swift` but I get this error:

```
Missing required modules: 'Crypto'
```

Did I miss out any step? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Found out where to get `Crypto.framework` for iOS!

In the Cartfile:

```
github "soffes/Crypto"
```

Then install the framework according to Carthage's standard instructions.